# SQL update using join impacting performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

Please help me in tuning below mentioned update statement,

```
  UPDATE t_cust
  SET cust_name = td.cust_name,
      cust_desc = td.cust_desc
  FROM t_cust tc
  JOIN t_data_cust td ON tc.cust_nr = td.cust_nr
  AND tc.start_validity_date = ISNULL(@execution_date,td.start_validity_date)
  AND (td.adj_id = @adj_id OR @adj_id IS NULL)
  AND ( td.ln_status = '0')
  WHERE td.cust_name            <> tc.cust_name
    OR td.cust_desc             <> tc.cust_desc
```

Comment: what is your problem ? how did you identity the query makes performance problems?? also query contains some syntax errors

Comment: please ignore ] syntax actually i am looking for an alternate of AND (td.adj_id = (@)adj_id OR (@)adj_id IS NULL) OR condition my customer table have millions of records and have trigger as well for history update

Comment: how much time it takes to update ? what is the time duration of executing this query ?

Comment: you can change the join like this 

 JOIN (select * from t_data_cust  where  tc.start_validity_date = ISNULL((at)execution_date,d.start_validity_date)
  AND (td.adj_id = (@)adj_id OR (@)adj_id IS NULL)
  AND ( td.ln_status = '0')
  ) td
ON tc.cust_nr = td.cust_nr
WHERE td.cust_name   <> tc.cust_name
    OR td.cust_desc    <> tc.cust_desc
---also if your problem is OR condition then write two updations one is with first or and second is with second one, but i think this is more better way

Comment: Post the query plan. Change to a select and establish whether it's the select part or the update part that is taking the time

Answer (score -1):

Move the `WHERE` statement into the `JOIN` conditions.

Otherwise it should run well, if it still doesn't, please provide more information.

Comment: Please explain down vote?  The OP asked for tuning and that's what I have provided.

Comment: moving a where condition into the join will make a functional difference if it's an outer join but it is unlikely to make a performance difference. It will probably result in no change to the query plan. sql server  is smart enough to decide whether to apply the predicate in the join or earlier on in a search

Comment: It is a JOIN, not an OUTER JOIN, so this is mute. 'Unlikely' and 'Probably', are not grounds for your argument, have you tested it in his environment? I have found many situations where performance is increased like this, mainly down to the logical processing order.
I appreciate you have a differing view, but my recommendation for an answer is as valid as any.

Comment: I think you mean moot. But regardless you are promoting a performance myth. The logical processing order is in the query plan and moving things from there where to the join does not change the plan.